# SQL Invalid syntax with OLEDB Oracle (11g) and C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oledb

Here is the query I want to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE name = @name AND pwd = @pwd;
```

My Connection String:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;User Id = HR; Password = hr;
```

Specifications:

- C# WinForms
- Oracle 11
- OleDBCommand as command
- Using Oracle XE

Steps I've tried:

- Script runs in sqldeveloper on the live server
- Connection opens
- Listener is up and running
- Parameters 'name' and 'pwd' got through and are sent

Error I'm getting:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, parameters are prefixed with `:` instead of `@`. Use that instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE name = :name AND pwd = :pwd;
```